# Does measuring an entangled pure state imply the result on the other subsystem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

From the definition of [entanglement of pure states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Pure_states):

Let the first system be in state $|\psi\rangle_A$ and the second in $|\psi\rangle_B$ with eigenstates $a_n|a_n\rangle$ and $b_m|b_m\rangle$ respectively.

We can write the combined wavefunction as
$$|\psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{n,m}c_{nm}|a_n\rangle|b_m\rangle$$

A non-separable or entangled state is one where the combined wavefunction cannot be expressed as a cartesian product of the two states $|\psi\rangle_{AB} \neq |\psi\rangle_A \otimes |\psi\rangle_B$.

As given on wikipedia, it is inseparable if for any vectors $[a_n],[b_m]$ at least for one pair of coordinates $a_{n},b_{m}$ we have $c_{nm}\neq a_{n}b_{m}$

**Question**

How does it follow from this definition of entanglement that if we measure $|\psi\rangle_A$ then we know the state of $|\psi\rangle_B$. It is clear from the example of Bell's states, however, how do we show this is true generally for any $N\times M$ vector space?

Comment: Note that the correct typesetting for kets is as `|\psi\rangle`.

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/430996/does-entangled-states-must-become-non-entangled-states-after-the-measurement) answer your question?

Comment: Are you sure that this is even true in the general case?

Comment: @Jakob This answer shows that any one part measurement gives a seperable final state

Comment: The final state could be seperable but still not certain. $|a_1\rangle \otimes (|b_1\rangle + |b_2\rangle)$ is seperable but $\psi_b$ is still a superposition, for example

Comment: @EmilioPisanty To be precise, the correct typesetting would be `\lvert ... \rangle`. This makes a difference e.g. in `\lvert\uparrow\rangle` vs. `|\uparrow\rangle`: $\lvert\uparrow\rangle$ vs. $|\uparrow\rangle$

Comment: @Norbert I find `|{\uparrow}\rangle` ($|{\uparrow} \rangle$) renders just fine ;-).

Comment: @Emilio Wow! I never stop to be surprised by TeX! Do you understand *why* it puts a space before the arrow?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch If I understand correctly, it treats `\uparrow` as a binary operator and spaces the objects around it accordingly. What I don't understand is why it treats the `|` and the `\rangle` differently, and why this does not happen with e.g. `+` (which should also be a binary operator). I guess that's a question for [tex.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not quite well-defined. Given a bipartite pure state $|\Psi\rangle$ shared by Alice and Bob, assuming Alice performed a measurement and found some $|\phi\rangle$, and assuming Bon knows the initial state $|\Psi\rangle$, then Bob oughts to describe his state as $(\langle \phi|\otimes I)|\Psi\rangle$. This is always *some* state, regardless of whether $|\Psi\rangle$ is entangled or not.
In this sense, regardless of there being entanglement, measuring one side of a system "implies" the state on the other side.
The same applies to general mixed states.

A more sensible interpretation of the question is as follows: *is it always true that, knowing Alice's measurement result, we can predict the result of Bob's measurement?*

The answer to this depends on the choices of measurement bases, as well as on the purity of the initial state.

1. Let the shared state be a bipartite pure separable state $|\Psi\rangle$. Then there cannot be any correlation between Alice's and Bob's measurement results, regardless of their choices of measurement basis.
2. Let the shared state be a bipartite pure *non-separable* state $|\Psi\rangle$.
   Then there is always *some* choice of measurement bases such that measurement results are fully correlated. This follows from the Schmidt decomposition: you can always find orthonormal bases $\{|u_i\rangle\}_i$ and $\{|v_i\rangle\}_i$ such that $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_i \sqrt{p_i}|u_i\rangle\otimes|v_i\rangle$ for some $p_i\ge0$ such that $\sum_i p_i=1$.

   If $|\Psi\rangle$ is *maximally* entangled, then *any* choice of measurement basis will result in full correlation. If the state is *not* maximally entangled, then bases need to be chosen appropriately: there is always a choice of measurement bases such that the measurement outcomes are *not* fully correlated.
3. If the shared state is not pure, then everything becomes more complicated. You can have a separable bipartite mixed state $\rho$ that still gives you correlations between the measurement outcomes. As an example, if $\rho=I/2$ is the one-qubit maximally mixed state, then measurement outcomes are fully correlated if Alice and Bob measure in the computational basis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's generally true. If we're looking at 2 entangled electrons that come from an initial state

$$ \psi = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(|0,0\rangle + |1,1\rangle)$$

(in the total angular momentum basis $|J,M\rangle$), then in terms of the spins, that is:

$$ \psi = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}[\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle -|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle)+ |\uparrow\uparrow\rangle]$$

So if I measure the 1st spin to be down, then the other is up, but if I measure it up, then the other is twice as likely to  be up than down.

Comment: Can you show that its not generally true?

Comment: In the last phrase, after the comma, shouldn't be "but if I measure it up"?